# How to run Alfresco Bundled Installer on Docker?

Tags: alfresco, docker

I am starting to use Docker, and now I would like to use it for running Alfresco instances.

I tried to install Alfresco using the single file installer obtained from:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_file_list_4.2.e (572Mb)

After inserting the installer file and run the recently created image, I execute:

```
root@3e8b72d208e4:/root# chmod u+x alfresco.sh 
root@3e8b72d208e4:/root# mv alfresco.sh alfresco.bin
root@3e8b72d208e4:/root# ./alfresco.bin 
root@3e8b72d208e4:/root#
```

After 1 second, the ./alfresco.bin process ends with no output. It is supposed to prompt some installer options.

I'm running Docker on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bits with 8Gb in RAM. What would be the right procedure to install Alfresco on a Docker container using the installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the bitrock installer requires tmpfs which in turn requires extra privileges for the executing the container. Run your container with

```
docker run -i -t -privileged <image> [<command>]
```

and execute

```
mount none /tmp -t tmpfs
```

within the container.

After that, the installer will run just fine.

Unfortately, things get messy if what you want is building an image from a dockerfile. `docker build` does not provide the `-privileged` switch or a `RUNP` instruction. You might want to have a look at https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1916 for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the docker-compose.yml of the community version. Here's one command that helped me generate the files needed.

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD:/app" -w "/app" -e XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/app/.yo_config -e npm_config_cache=/app/.cache node:alpine sh -c "npm i -g yo generator-alfresco-docker-installer && yo alfresco-docker-installer"
```